# why is blevel null for some indexes in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, index

I was trying to see the b-tree levels for indexes and to my surprise I see some of them are set to null.

```
SELECT index_name, blevel FROM user_indexes ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Their name starts with "SYS_"(picture attached below). SO I am assuming they are system generated indexes? Maybe of primary keys? Either ways I am curious as to why they are null. I can understand if the value is 0 which mean everything is in leaf nodes and it will just take 1 hop for unique scan to get the data.

[image]

Comment: They look like sys schema objects so they might play by their own rules. But the most likely answer is there are no nodes in them at all.

Comment: For quite a few stats columns (including blevel)  in `*_indexes`  docs says   "Column names followed by an asterisk are populated only if you collect statistics on the index using the ANALYZE statement or the DBMS_STATS package. "  I guess the engine  doesn't execute either of these commands against some or all system tables indexes ...

Comment: Those are lob indexes, it just may be a property of lob indexes. You can try collecting them but I am not sure what oracle would do internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes whose the name start with `SYS_IL..` are LOB indexes.

`BLEVEL` is a property of B-tree indexes, and does not make sense for LOB indexes.

Even if you collect statistics, `BLEVEL` for such an index will remain null.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Balazs for the info.

Did some research around this and looks like -

A lob is simply a pointer and it points to a data chuncks that make that lob. So when you create a lob column you automatically get a lob index so that lob data chunks are retrieved faster and segment that holds this data chunks.

Use following queries to verify the same -

```
SELECT index_name,INDEX_TYPE, blevel FROM user_indexes where blevel is null and index_name like 'SYS_IL%%' ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

To see associated segments -

```
select segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name, bytes, max_extents from user_segments where segment_name in (
SELECT index_name FROM user_indexes where blevel is null and index_name like 'SYS_IL%%' 
);
```

You can delete this by dropping that table that has lob column or the column itself.